# Draw centered circle

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a centered circle using fragment shader. I don't quite understand how to accomplish this. This is what I got so far, but the result is a white screen.

I want to be able to draw it any size and be able to change the offsets as I like (move the circle around).

```
void main()
{
    float radius        = 10.0;

    float viewWidth     = 340.0;
    float viewHeight    = 500.0;

    float offsetX       = viewWidth  / 2.0;
    float offsetY       = viewHeight / 2.0;

    float factorX       = viewWidth  / ( 360.0 / 6.3 );
    float factorY       = viewHeight / ( 360.0 / 6.3 );

    float angleX        = gl_FragCoord.x / factorX;
    float angleY        = gl_FragCoord.y / factorY;

    float x             = offsetX + ( sin( angleX ) * radius );
    float y             = offsetY + ( cos( angleY ) * radius );
    float c             = x + y;

    gl_FragColor = vec4( c, c, c, 1.0 );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, this program runs separately for each individual fragment.  Each one need only decide if it's in or out of the circle.  No need to use `sin` and `cos` here, just measure the distance from the center of the viewport, to see if the fragment is in the circle.

Here's a disc, which is even simpler:  http://glslsandbox.com/e#28997.0

```
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main( void ) {

    vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy ) - 0.5;
    position.x *= resolution.x / resolution.y;

    float circle = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.2, 0.21, length(position));

    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( circle ), 1.0 );

}
```

And here's a circle, made by tweaking the disc a little:  http://glslsandbox.com/e#28997.1

```
uniform vec2 resolution;

void main( void ) {

    vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy ) - 0.5;
    position.x *= resolution.x / resolution.y;

    float circle = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.003, 0.005, abs(length(position) - 0.2));

    gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3( circle ), 1.0 );

}
```